# measure of the union taken from a finite subcollection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $c>0$ be a constant and $\mathcal C$ be a collection of balls in $\mathbb R^d$ such that $m(\cup_{B\in \mathcal C}B)>c$. I wonder if we can find finitely many $B_i$'s from $\mathcal C$ such that $m(\cup_{i}B_i)>c$. $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Are these necessarily open balls? If so, I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @Clayton Does it fail for non-open balls or arbitrary measurable sets?

Comment: Correct. If you allow closed balls, then each ball could be a singleton where the collection must be uncountable. In that case, finitely many will always have measure zero.

Comment: There seems to be a modern style of teaching Measure Theory that avoids mentioning inner measure.   $S$ is Lebesgue measurable iff $m^o(S)=m^i(S)=m(S)$ where $m^o$ is Lebesgue outer measure, and the Lebesgue inner measure is  $m^i(S)=\sup \{m(T):T=\overline T \subset S\}.$... If $S$ is Lebesgue measurable and $c<m(S)<\infty$ then  $c<m(T)$ for some $compact $ $ T\subset S.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your balls are open balls. Since $\mathbb  R^{d}$ is second countable we can express any union of open balls as a countable union, say $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty } B_n$. Since $m(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty } B_n)=lim_{n\to \infty }m(\cup_{k=1}^{n } B_k)$ we can find $n$ such that  $m(\cup_{k=1}^{n } B_k)>c$